# How can I upload file to server

Tags: php

I am trying to create a file upload form. The form works correctly and upload the file to my system folder but when I use an online folder (http://www.google.com/uploadedcv) it does not work. Please can someone assist me with this?

Here is the code below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fileupload'])){
if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: ".$_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}

$allowedEXTs = array("cvs","txt");
$extension = @end(explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
//$extension = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
//$extension = $extension[1];
//Supported File Type Below:
if(((!$_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")||
$_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/png"||$_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/jpeg"||
$_FILES["file"]["type"]==("plain/txt")&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <20000)
&& in_array($extension,$allowedExts))){

//{echo $_FILES["file"]["type"] ." not supported.";}

if(file_exists("uploadedcv/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo " Sorry, your CV (" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . ") already exist in our server.";
}else{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"http://www.google.com/uploadedcv/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
}
}
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
<style type="text/css">
fieldset{
        background-color: #BDDFFF;
        width:50%;
        }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<label>FILENAME</label>
<input type ="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="fileupload"/>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, understand that the above code worked correctly when I tried uploading to my local computer folder. The only issue is uploading to my web folder instead of my local folder.

Comment: Always remember to quote the exact errors you are getting - "it doesn't work" is never a helpful description of the problem. In this case the problem seems clear though - you can't move files to a HTTP location, much less to one that you don't control. You need to use a local filesystem path.

Comment: You can't uploade your file into google's server! o.O Or are you trying to hack google? :)

Comment: lollzzz...anyway the google url is just an example. Originally I replaced the google url with my own url.

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload files to another server(its possible only via ftp). And why are you trying to move it to google? o.O

Change your code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"http://www.google.com/uploadedcv/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

With this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploadedcv/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

This is for uploading the file in the folder where your code is trying to check if it already exists:

```
if(file_exists("uploadedcv/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
```